# Ext5 If typeAhead is enabled the combo must be editable: true

Tags: combobox, extjs5

I moved from Ext4 to 5 and except ALL the other errors and changes i have also this
[E] Ext.form.field.ComboBox.initComponent(): If typeAhead is enabled the combo must be editable: true -- please change one of those settings.

Why and how can i solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typeahead is function which completes text in combo when only one record from store matches query. You can see how it works on my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rvew097f/2/
Try to type 'Adam'.
Knowing how it works, it start to be obvious that it makes no sense for configuration where `editable` is set to `false` and `typeAhead` is set to `true`.

To correct this error, just search code for `typeAhead: true` and set it to `false` always when there is also `editable: false`.

BTW apparently in Ext JS `typeAhead` functionality is broken and that's why in my demo I've overriden store and `find` method.